# The delete function in this employee DB doesn't work

Tags: c, database

I am trying to fix this code in C for an employee database. Employee can be searched by ID and if no record found then the 'Sorry record not found!' message is displayed.

```
void del() {
    char id[10];
    printf("\n\t Delete which record?:");
    gets(id);
    curr = start;
    if (strcmp(start->name, name) == 0) {
        start = start->next;
        free(curr);
        printf("\n\t First record deleted!");
        return;
    }

    while (curr) {
        if (strcmp(curr->next->name, name) == 0) {
            curr->next = curr->next->next;      
            printf("\n\n\t Record Deleted!");
            return;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n\t Sorry record not found!");
}
```

Comment: See [Why is the `gets()` function too dangerous to be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/) for reasons why you should not use `gets()`. If you use it, use a vastly bigger array than 10 characters (perhaps 4096, or 512 bytes; it still isn't safe though). Check the return value from it (or from `fgets()`, the recommended replacement) before using the result. It would help if you provided an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), or at least the structure definition. Report errors on `stderr` and include the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing `while (curr)`, you should test `while (curr->next)`, otherwise you will dereference a NULL pointer when `del` does not find a matching record.  This function will also fail if the database is empty, because you dereference `start` without first testing that it is non `NULL`.

Note that you should not use `gets()`. This function was removed from the latest C Standard, it cannot be used safely: your program will invoke undefined behavior if the user inputs more than 9 characters for the employee name.

Using a pointer to pointer, you can avoid special casing the initial list element:

```
void del() {
    char id[128];
    Employee **pp = &start;

    printf("\n\t Delete which record?: ");
    if (!fgets(id, sizeof id, stdin))
        return;
    id[strcspn(id, "\n")] = '\0'; /* strip the \n if present */

    while (*pp) {
        if (strcmp((*pp)->name, id) == 0) {
            Employee *p = *pp;
            *pp = p->next;
            free(p);  
            printf("\n\n\t Record Deleted!");
            return;
        }
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n\t Sorry record not found!");
}
```